AMD 7965WX CPU is not thermally throttling in Ubuntu 23.10
My CPU (AMD 7965WX) is not properly thermally throttling, and is exceeding the max operating temperature of 95C without throttling (it has gotten as high as 98 before I shut it off). I am running Ubuntu 23.10, and using an ASUS WRX90E-SAGE motherboard.
If I run CPU intensive processes that max out all cores (especially if my dual GPUs are running heavy loads at the same time), I can quickly exceed the maximum temp. I'm worried that my CPU is going to get damaged.
When I look at /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors there are only powersave and performance available (powersave is what it is currently set to).
Also, when I try to set to performance governor in /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils and reboot, it has no effect. It just stays in powersave mode (which I understand will not throttle).
How can I ensure that my CPU will not exceed a specified temperature threshold (ideally ~92C or less)? Is there any way to also throttle the GPUs when CPU temps are too high?
